# Is it wrong or not advised to have a thread locked for a long time? Tcp related

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on a server program with a slotmanager thread (queue of references to other tcpthreads waiting for a connection). Sort of like when you are waiting in queue for a game server. My initial plan was to have the slotmanager thread wait and then will continue if notified(client waiting). Then the tpcthreads would just request an update on the status every X ms.

My other options would be to have the slotmanager thread finish when the queue is empty then start a new one if its not already running and the queue has a waiting client in or have the TCPthread wait, which could result in the connection timing out.

Comment: By lock I did mean a condition variable, which would be notified when waiting client is added to the queue.

Comment: good... if you do that properly it should work out for you.  There's nothing wrong with having a thread delayed "for a long time" waiting for a condition to be signalled.